# How can I tell if a camera employs active or passive infrared - or neither?

Tags: infrared, camera

In brief;
Is there some way to figure out if a security/web/IP camera is using passive infrared, active infrared or no infrared at all without opening up the camera?

Details;
My Mom is in a nursing home. I want to put a camera there to monitor her 24/7. Most security cameras use active infrared, but long term exposure to active infrared could be bad for health (eye damage). Instead, I was thinking about using a simple web camera because they don't come with any night vision (so no chance of active infrared).  I was looking at the Logitech Brio 4k web camera but then I noticed it has two LEDs on the outside. LEDs on cameras are something I associate with infrared.  I also noticed the Brio boasts its ability to see in low light conditions using something Logitech calls "Redlight 3". Infact, most of Logitech's cameras have the Redlight tech. I e-mailed Logitech and asked if the Brio uses any infrared, they replied it is proprietary technology and they can not tell me either way. Is there a way I could figure it out?

Thank you.

Comment: IR causes eye damage? Citation needed.

Comment: I never read that IR causes eye damage, but if you must check: many (most?) telephone cameras can see at least near infrared, you can use that. Check first if the camera can see the IR from your TV remote.

Comment: @Neil_UK **bright** infrared could cause damage because pupillary response does not work for those wavelengths. eg: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366731/how-do-i-determine-eye-safety-limits-for-ir-leds

Comment: The (relatively poor) IR filter on your cellphone camera will be overwhelmed by LEDs far below the level that can cause harm to your eyes, so take a picture of the light. If it looks dark it's either not an IR LED or so weak as to be harmless.

Comment: @ocrdu - thank you. i will try that.

Comment: @user1850479 - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> long term exposure to active infrared could be bad for health (eye damage.)

Just for reference: https://medium.com/@alex.kilpatrick/ir-illumination-and-eye-safety-f0804673ca7 does a, according to my *very* amateur insight into vision safety, sensible analysis for a *massive* infrared *floodlight* and comes to the conclusion that you shouldn't sit in front of it and start straight into it for more than 16 minutes, because it *hypothetically could* damage your cornea.

Now, that whole floodlight is massive – it emits 14 W/sr. A very bright flashlight might do maybe 3 W/sr in the center of its light cone, and for small infrared LEDs you're more talking about 5 mW/sr to 50 mW/sr (pretty beefy LED already); let your camera have 16 of these, and let them all be strangely aligned exactly at the eye of your mother (won't physically happen, they're aligned to illuminate the room, not a single point), then we're talking 80 to 800 mW/sr. Your mother's eyes are going to be fine, assuming you mount the infrared light at the ceiling, so that she can't be closer than maybe 1.5m to 2.0m to it.

> LEDs are something that I associate with infrared.

that is nonsensical. LEDs are *light*-emitting diodes, they can basically emit light of any wavelength, and for webcams, you'd use some that are mostly visible-light region, if you're aiming for the camera to pick up an image that doesn't look very scary to the user. (Note that there is laptop and smartphone cameras with IR sensitivity and active IR illumination, for biometric unlocking reasons. They're save.)

> I e-mailed Logitech and asked if the Brio uses any infrared, they replied it is proprietary technology and they can not tell me either way.

That would be stupidly simple to test (look at the camera with a IR-sensitive camera, like the cheapest webcam you can buy, and look whether it shines to know whether it emits near-IR, or shine an infrared LED at it, e.g. by pressing a button on your old TV remote, and look whether the camera picks it up). That's not a secret they could keep for more than a minute after the first camera sells ;) What the support very kindly is telling you there is that they don't want to deal with individual slightly paranoid would-be customers of a low-cost mass-market products, as explaining infrared, LEDs, vision safety, cameras, spectral sensitivities, … is something that support isn't even educated to do, so it would take a development engineer, whose hour is worth *many* more cameras than you would buy in a lifetime. And it still would have a nice chance of not helping anyone – what if they explained to you in great technical detail how safe the camera is, and you wouldn't believe them? So, as mean as that sounds, that was kind of an understandable reaction to someone who, had they had the knowledge to assess safety of a system given confidential specifications, would be able to get these specifications within minutes.

Comment: "there is laptop and smartphone cameras with IR sensitivity and active IR illumination, for biometric unlocking reasons."  ....yes, Logitech said the LED on the brio was used for biometric.