Infrared eye tracking - safe levels of infrared exposure on the eyes
I'm making an infrared eye tracker where an infrared light will be shone on one of the user's eyes, and a camera will capture the user's gaze, and I have a 940mm IR LED for this purpose. I have the LED connected to an embedded camera board that provides a 3.3V up to 2A, connected through a current limiting resistor in series. I've picked 5 values of current limiting resistors: 56Ω, 100Ω, 150Ω, 180Ω and 220Ω, which have the corresponding measured current draw (I_f)  of 30mA, 15mA, 10mA, 7.9mA and 7.8mA respectively (rounded off). I am faced with the problem to select from any of these as well as vary the distance and see which one provides the best illumination within safe limits, and does not have to be placed at an absurd distance away from the eyes, like 20cm away for example.
Here's what I can control: forward current (I_f) of the infrared LED (through changing the resistor), and distance the LED is placed away from the eyes (assume LED is normal to the eye).
Here's what is fixed to me: the LED itself (and characteristics) and the supply voltage of 3.3V.
Here's what I need to know: What's a safe amount of time of exposure to the infrared LED per session at a given forward current and distance? What is the period of time the user must rest between these sessions? How close can I place the IR LED to my eyes?
I now need to draft up a risk assessment to justify my choice of distance, power used, time per session and time of rest between sessions. I've read up on some literature regarding safe levels of infrared on the eye and I've been trying to find thresholds or guidances that provides me answers to these, and here are the most relevants one I could find:
https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a7efbaf40f0b62305b8466a/HPA-CRCE-016_for_website.pdf
https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/AB191-4-luxeon-ir-family-eye-safety-application-brief.pdf
Some of these equations require spectral irradiance which is not provided from the data sheet. How do I obtain the spectral irradiance in W.m^-2.nm^-1 in order to fit these calculations?

Asked before, read this discussion: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366731/how-do-i-determine-eye-safety-limits-for-ir-leds

Hi @Mark, this post you've linked to seems to focus on remote infrared, which is often not pointed directly at the eye, and it is also not continuous. In my case, I am asking about the safety thresholds for an infrared LED pointed directly at someone's eyes continuously, for a period of time. It also does not provide said thresholds for my application. I understand that my level of expertise is insufficient, hence why I'm here to ask for help finding justifications to back up whatever values I choose to set for distance and forward current mathematically and based on regulations.

@MarkLeavitt Another thing to mention is I'm not just looking for comments on whether IR is harmful or not to the eyes - I'm looking for the math and related equations, to concretely justify the values chosen.

The ANSI standards cover calculations for IR eye exposure and hazard levels in great deal. You should start with those.

Hi @user1850479, would you be able to provide a link? So far my searches only returned standards for safety glasses.

Probably ANSI Z80.36, which covers "instruments that direct optical radiation into or at the eye", although check the ANSI page.

@user1850479 can I confirm this is what you're referring to: https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/vc%20(asc%20z80)/ansiz80362021
If so, the pdf costs 82.50usd and I don't have any funding to purchase it...

That is the standard I was referring to, but again, it is up to you to determine if that is the right standard for your application and your region.  If you cannot buy a copy, you may be able to get one from a university library.

Spectral irradiance is the power per wavelength per area on something, in this case the eye.  You will not be able to look that up in a datasheet since it is a property of the device you are building (if it is in any datasheet it would be one your write for your device).  You'll need to calculate it analytically or simulate it using modeling tools.  Since you think this is "gibberish" it sounds like you may need to get an optical engineer or a physicist involved in this project to help you with the calculations.

The information is actually in the datasheet, but it takes some application of solid angle geometry and calculus to get it to the form you need.
You have the radiant flux in mW/sr on page 2. From this you can calculate the total power reaching the eye given the distance. Either making a simplifying assumption that the apparent size of the eye seen from the LED is small enough and the LED is pointed straight at it, or using the spatial distribution graph on page three. This gives you a power in W, you can get the irradiance in W/m2 if you divide by the area of the subtending circle.
Then take the graph which plots relative radiant intensity against wavelength (page 3). This is the spectral irradiance, only it's been normalised so the peak is 1. Integrate the area under the curve and rescale the Y axis so that the integral is equal to the value in mW/m2 that you obtained at the previous step, and you've got your result.
Now, this is for the irradiance on the surface of the eyeball. If you need it on the surface of the retina, then you've got to do the calculation differently to account for the lens, but the same general principles apply.

Hi, I apologize, I'm very confused about most of what you said, firstly I thought the value provided in mW/Sr is radiant intensity? How exactly do I go about calculating the total power reaching the eye given the distance? Would you be able to provide an example calculation to help me understand better?
